# Keeping real estate in Israel

Tags: eretz-yisrael, real-estate, messianic-redemption

When the World to Come is in full effect (messianic age, beis hamikdash, resurrection of dead), will current real estate owners in Israe need to relinquish their rights to the property for it to be reapportioned (or forced to sell) or will everyone who owns land in Israel be allowed to keep it?

Answer (score 1):

See gemara bava basra 122a that it will be reapportioned but it's possible that if one happens to own real estate where his shevet is given its portion, he might get lucky and end up keeping it if he makes a good case for himself at the local bais din.

> [תניא עתידה ארץ ישראל שתתחלק לשלשה עשר שבטים](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%90#%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA)